# Using R CMD SHLIB with OpenMP not for package building

Tags: c, r, shared-libraries, openmp

The (R) program I'm writing is at one point able to write C source code files containing OpenMP instructions in order to speed up the resulting program (these files mainly contain a set of differential equations whose results are written to an array - as these steps can be executed independently, I thought it to be a good idea to parallelize them using omp sections). As the files generated this way are supposed to be used in another part of my program I also use R to compile them using `system(R CMD SHLIB...)` at runtime, as this approach seemed to have the advantage that, using `R CMD SHLIB`, no specific compiler would need to be imposed on the user.

The problem I'm now facing is that I can't pass the `-fopenmp` (or `-openmp`) compiler directive to `R CMD SHLIB` and it is not possible to use a Makevars file providing additional compiler flags (or ideally `$SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS`) when not building an R package - which I'm not doing in this case, so `R CMD SHLIB` compiles the file I give it. Without OpenMP paralellization, however, as I see no way how to pass the according flags to `SHLIB` in this situation.

Is there any possibility to use `R CMD SHLIB` for this task anyway or will I have to sacrifice portability by internally specifying a compiler for OpenMP compilation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must use `R CMD SHLIB` as opposed to a Makefile or package, I think you want to modify an environment variable such as `PKG_CPPFLAGS` or `PKG_CXXFLAGS`, which you can from inside R via `Sys.setenv()`.

R itself now uses OpenMP and the compiler option you desire is available on recent R systems:

```
edd@max:~$ grep OPENMP /etc/R/Makeconf 
SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS = -fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS = -fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_FCFLAGS = -fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_FFLAGS = -fopenmp
edd@max:~$
```

That's from a standard R 2.15.1 on a Debian / Ubuntu system.

Comment: You probably want `Sys.setenv()`. Here is an actual line from package `inline`:  `Sys.setenv( CLINK_CPPFLAGS = flag )`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in R with:

```
system("R CMD COMPILE filename.c CFLAGS=-fopenmp")
system("R CMD SHLIB filename.o")
```